# Piping commands after a piped xargs

Tags: shell, find, pipe, xargs

HP-UX ***** B.11.23 U ia64 **** unlimited-user license

```
find . -type d -name *log* | xargs ls -la
```

gives me the directory names (the ones which contain `log` in the directory name) followed by all files within that directory.

The directories  `/var/opt/SID/application_a/log/`,  `/var/opt/SID/application_b/log/`,  `/var/opt/SID/application_c/log/` and so on contain log files.

I want only the two latest logfiles to be listed by the `ls` command, which I usually find using `ls -latr | tail -2`.

The output has to be something like this..

```
/var/opt/SID/application_a/log/
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user1    user1      59698 Jun 11  2013 log1
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user1    user1      59698 Jun 10  2013 log2
/var/opt/SID/application_b/log/
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user1    user1      59698 Jun 11  2013 log1
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user1    user1      59698 Jun 10  2013 log2
/var/opt/SID/application_c/log/
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user1    user1      59698 Jun 11  2013 log1
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user1    user1      59698 Jun 10  2013 log2
```

`find . -type d -name *log* | xargs ls -la | tail -2` does not give me the above result. What I get is a list of last two files of 
`find . -type d -name *log* | xargs ls -la` command.

So can I pipe commands after a piped `xargs`? How else do I query, to get the resultant list of files in the above format?

```
find . -type d -name *log* | xargs sh -c "ls -ltr | tail -10"
```

gives me a list of ten directory names inside the current directory which happens to be `/var/opt/SID` and that is also not what I want.

Comment: You should quote the `*log*` otherwise the shell will expand it.

Comment: Be aware that `sh -c` expects the command name (parameter 0) as its second argument, so you should always do `find . -type d -name *log* | xargs sh -c "ls -ltr | tail -10" lstail` (notice the `lstail` at the end, which will serve as `$0` for the created shell). Otherwise the first of your results will fill that role and go unused.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You are almost there. In your last command, you can use `-I` to do the `ls` correctly

> `-I replace-str`
>
>   Replace  occurrences of
>   *replace-str*
>   in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline character.  Implies
>   `-x`
>   and
>   `-L 1`
>   .

So, with

```
find . -type d -name "*log*" | xargs -I {} sh -c "echo {}; ls -la {} | tail -2"
```

you will `echo` the dir found by `find`, then do the `ls | tail` on it.

Comment: find . -type d -name "*log*" | xargs -I {} sh -c "echo {};ls -ltr {} | grep -E \"file_in|file_out\"|tail -5"
I used this one.

Comment: I do with `xargs -n 1 sh -c 'echo $0'`

Comment: on macOS the replacement didn't work within the quoted command, so `echo $0` was helpful (and more understandable)

Comment: To make it work with filenames with spaces, use `-print0`, `xargs -0` and escape `{}` into double quotes _inside_ the `sh` command: `find . -type d -name "*log*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c "echo \"{}\";ls -la \"{}\" | tail -2"`

Comment: I use "xargs -n 1 sh -c "echo \$0 | $func"` if I need to use the $func variable

Comment: why does xargs see the pipe. Shouldn't it be handled by bash?

Answer (score 12):

Just in addition to fredtantini and as a general clarification (since the docs are a bit confusing):

The `xargs -I {}` will take the '{}' characters from the standard input and replace them with whatever comes in from the pipe. This means you could actually replace `{}` with any character combination (maybe to better suite your preferred programming flavor). **For example**: `xargs -I % sh -c "echo %"`. If you always use the `xargs -I {}` you can replace it with `xargs -i` as it is the shorthand. **EDIT**: The `xargs -i` option has been deprecated, so stick to the `xargs -I{}`.

The `sh -c` will tell your bash/shell to read the next command from a string and not from the standard input. So writing `sh -c "echo something"` is equivalent to `echo something`.

The `xargs -I {} sh -c "echo {}"` will read the input you created with `sh -c` which is `echo {}`. Since you told it to replace `{}` with the arguments you got from the pipe, that's what will happen.

You can easily test this even without piping, just type the above command in a terminal. Whatever you write next will get outputted to the terminal (Ctrl-D to exit).

In the `ls -la {}` command the same thing happens again. The `{}` is replaced with the contents of the pre-pipe command.

Comment: "If you always use the `xargs -I {}` you can replace it with `xargs -i` as it is the shorthand." Note that `-i` is not POSIX.

Comment: It seems that the ```-i``` has been deprecated anyway...

Answer (score 10):

GNU Parallel makes this kind of tasks easy:

```
find . -type d -name "*log*" | parallel --tag "ls -la {} | tail -2"
```

If you do not want to do a full install of GNU Parallel you can do a minimal installation: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README